# Filter rows of a dataframe based on a column when both column name and values to filter are in variables

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following scenario I get an empty data frame

```
D = data.frame(X = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
vals = c("x1", "x2")
col = "X"
dplyr::filter(D, col %in% vals)
```

But doing it as following works

```
dplyr::filter(D, X %in% vals)
```

I cannot hardcode the name of the column nor the values by which to filter. I need the first scenario to work.

Comment: @tmfmnk there is a slight difference in the questions, in this question we are trying to filter rows on multiple values. But the solutions in both questions should work by changing the filtering with `==` or `%in%` ?

Comment: Sure, it is working. You can do `filter(D, !!as.name(col) %in% vals)` or 
`filter(D, UQ(as.name(col)) %in% vals)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
dplyr::filter(D, !! rlang::sym(col) %in% vals)
#    X
#1 x1
#2 x2
```

---

Or another option is `filter_at`

```
D %>%
    filter_at(vars(col), any_vars(. %in% vals))
```